# Python - print a list adding empty lines at determined points

Tags: python

I have a list that contains logs, and I am trying to add an empty line between specific blocks. So when I get to the end of a specific block, I can see a bit of separation, instead of looking like a continuous list.

```
EX:
log a:
kdsaldklsadkaslk
kasldkasldkasldkasldk

log a1:
lkpadkfaldkfdsl
klsdkfldskfsdl
```

So far I've tried all that I was able to find online, but I was unsuccessful. Either I am forced to add anything but an empty line (like a sequence of ----- for example), or the space added will be added to every single line (which is not what I want).

If I add in the list the empty line, like

```
log_list.append(" \n")
```

when I print the list using

```
print "\n".join(log_list)
```

all the empty lines that I have added are not printed.

But if I add any character to the append command, then it will be printed.

Is there any option that is automatically taking off the empty lines in a list, when I do the join command? Otherwise I do not understand why I cannot have an empty line in the list.

Is there another way to print out lists? I've always seen printing lists with the join command (all my objects in the list are strings).

Thanks!

Comment: what is the format of your initial lists? is it like `['log a:', 'strA1', 'strA2', 'strA3', ..., 'strAN', 'log b:', 'strB1', 'strB2', ..., 'strBM',...]`? In this case you might want to scan the list with a regular expression or so and add an empty string between `'strAN'` and `'log b:'`, so that you can do `"\n".join(log_list)`.

Comment: `log_list.append(" \n")` should give you two blank lines. `log_list.append("")` is probably what you want, but you need to do it in the right places as you create the list, not just append to the end of it

Comment: Could you be reading the output in a text editor that uses Windows style [newlines](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline)?

Comment: nvlass: the list is created while I read from a text file, so each line in the text file is saved in a position of the list, in the order they are read (I use [for line in file: log_list.append(line)] )

Comment: gnibbler: not sure why I do not get blank lines; I just run the py script, reading the log file, from console.

Comment: Jason: all is done via console, so no external editor is used. The log output is a plain utf8 txt file in unix format; I just grab it and process it with the script, without even opening it with texteditor or similar (I read it with cat or more, if I have to)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For me, this works (showing that there is no monkey business with appending a `\n` and then joining with a `\n`):

```
>>> log_list = ['a']
>>> log_list.append('\n')
>>> log_list.append('b')
>>> log_list.append('c')
>>> print '\n'.join(log_list)
a


b
c
```

What did you do differently?

Comment: If I run the same in console without running the script, I get indeed the empty line added; while when I run the script it won't happen...I am trying to revise the script to make it as simple as this one and see if in facts the line is added. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If the list is already created, you can for example insert a blank line before every line ending with `":"` like this

```
print "\n".join("\n"+s if s.endswith(":") else s for s in log_list)
```

It's probably clearer to just use a loop though

```
for s in log_list:
    if s.endswith(":"):
        print
    print s
```

You can change the condition to suit your requirements, eg `s.startswith("log ")`